# Does Modernizr.js help in showing css 3 and html 5 on older browsers and how?

Tags: javascript, html, css, modernizr

I used css 3, html 5 in a web page and I want to use Modernizr to show some html5 attributes and some css 3 such as border-radius on old browsers,
Does Modernizr help in this and how run it.

Comment: Just check the doc on the official site? http://www.modernizr.com/docs/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modernizr will only help you detect certain features, so you'll have to add the JS fixes yourself.

In case you want to go for a pre-packaged solution this might be of help: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills

In your case this might be the way to go: http://css3pie.com/

Answer (score 2):

Modernizr doesn’t add missing functionality to older browsers other than the HTML5 Shiv so that you can use and style the new semantic elements from HTML5. The other answers already show some polyfill options, however, I recommend you reconsider adding purely-visual effects like `border-radius` to older browsers that way. Polyfills slow the older browsers down (sometimes very significantly) and make the overall experience *much worse* for those users.

Answer (score 0):

You can use modernizr to detect what's available, e.g. rounded corners. If it's not, you can degrade gracefully via the modernizr API, or even use a plug-in to smoke and mirrors the feature.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Modernizr.load({
        test: Modernizr.borderradius,
        nope: 'script/jquery.corner.js',
        callback: function () {
            $('article').corner();
            $('figure').corner();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Code snippet taken from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2011/08/04/html5-part-4-using-html5-while-retaining-support-for-older-browsers.aspx

Comment: man, i've seen this code snippet around i i find it mostly useless because of the `$('article').corner();
                $('figure').corner();` -_- where is the dynamicness in that.

Answer (score 0):

Modernizr does not help with CSS3. (You could use [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) for this, but it has some cross-domain issues you'll want to read about.)

Modernizr does have [IEPP for HTML5 shim support](http://paulirish.com/2011/the-history-of-the-html5-shiv/) and it comes with [YepNope.js as Modernizr.load](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#load), which is a great polyfills loader mechanism so you can load your own support for older browsers. That will help you drop in support for attributes like `pattern` and `placeholder` without overloading browsers that have native support for it.

Answer (score 0):

Modernizr internally uses the same JS code that you would use otherwise..
e.g. If you want to check for "input" placeholder support, using Native way, you would use;

```
function support_input_placeholder() {  
    var i = document.createElement('input');
    return 'placeholder' in i;
}
```

While the Modernizr way to check would be like

```
function support_input_modern() {   
    if (Modernizr.input.placeholder) 
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

But the above code has the same internal working as the native way...

So ideally, I would prefer native way for simpler and lesser amount of checking...

Only for very complex things, should we go for Modernizr